# How to query by multiple fields of object in array of a document in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

Hi I am newbie of Elasticsearch. And I want to query documents by the value of its field (type:array). Example like this:

```
docx=people:[
{id:1,role:admin},
{id:2,role:other}
]
docy=people:[
{id:1,role:other},
{id:2,role:admin}
]
```

My query is `people.id:1 AND people.role:admin`. My expected result is only docx, but ES also returns docy. I know it's wrong but how can I do it in ES. So how a query string can be to filter only document like docx. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show more details how your data looks like? It could work with nested data types, but they've got performance penalty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [nested data-type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) in your case, as object data-type is flattened and treated separately which is causing both the documents to match the result, will add a working example.

But please be aware that nested data-type becomes costly when you have large data-set and a high number of concurrent queries as explained in [go-jek's medium blog.](https://blog.gojekengineering.com/elasticsearch-the-trouble-with-nested-documents-e97b33b46194)

Please follow [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20140810095505/http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/managing-relations-inside-elasticsearch/) blog which highlights your issue in detail.

**Working example with proper mapping**

**Index mapping**

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "name" : {
             "type" :   "text"
            },
            "people": {
                "type": "nested"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**index sample doc**

```
{
    "name": "bar",
    "people": 
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "role": "other"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "role": "admin"
        }
    ]
}
```

**And second sample doc**

```
{
    "name": "foo",
    "people": 
    [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "role": "admin"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "role": "other"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Search query**

```
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "people",
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "people.id": 1
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "people.role": "admin"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**And expected search result**

```
"hits": [
            {
                "_index": "matchphrase",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 1.6931472,
                "_source": {
                    "name": "foo",
                    "people": [
                        {
                            "id": 1,
                            "role": "admin"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 2,
                            "role": "other"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
```

Comment: I'v tried it and the result I'v got is: failed to create query: [nested] nested object under path [people] is not of nested type. How to fix it?

Comment: @iamatsundere181 did you use the same mapping which I posted in my answer??

Comment: I changed but it returned error like that: cannot change object mapping from non-nested to nested. Should I clear and re-index all the data to adapt that?

Comment: @iamatsundere181, yes, you have to create a new index and re-index all the data to adapt it :)

Comment: @iamatsundere181 looking forward to get the feedback from you.

Comment: Hi @Elasticsearch Ninja , long time, your solution is perfect! I will mark it, but in my situation, I have to work around to set another field which is used for searching purposes. Btw, thanks a lot!

Comment: @iamatsundere181 thanks a lot for marking an answer, glad i was helpful and better late than never :)